# Searchkick, search by parents names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using `searchkick` gem, which provides to my very powerful searching.

When I type this for my Items:

```
Item.search 'computer'
```

It will return me `Item` models which has this string in its attributes.

If I have `Item` objects with names `SuperCalc1`, `ExtraTurboSmart`and `WoodenPC` and `Item` model is belongs to `Category` model and category of these items are `Computers`, how can I search these items by name of its parent model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're either going to have to index the `Category` model and search by that, or add the model to `Item`'s index:

```
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    category: category.name
  }
end
```

and then reindex.

Comment: I have read somewhere that I need to write `attributes,merge` inside of it. Is it important?

Comment: That should be used if you want all of the default attributes in the index as well. That will merge those attributes with whatever you define next. Otherwise (and either way) you can explicitly list the attributes you want to be indexed.